# lodash sort array of string arrays

Tags: arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have the following data:

```
[["Balin Sankar","10","English","91.1408767700195"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Maths","88.1268997192383"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Science","90.3445739746094"],
["Balin Sankar","10","History","87.1235580444336"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Geography","88.2675628662109"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Civics","89.6238479614258"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Economics","86.5236434936523"]]
```

I need to sort these based on the 4th value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need lodash for that. It can be achieved with a regular `sort`:

```js
var array = [["Balin Sankar","10","English","91.1408767700195"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Maths","88.1268997192383"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Science","90.3445739746094"],
["Balin Sankar","10","History","87.1235580444336"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Geography","88.2675628662109"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Civics","89.6238479614258"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Economics","86.5236434936523"]];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[3] - b[3];
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could pass lodash's [**sortBy**](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) function a function that selects the fourth item in the list:

```
var result = _.sortBy(data, item => parseFloat(item[3]))
```

```js
var data = [["Balin Sankar","10","English","91.1408767700195"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Maths","88.1268997192383"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Science","90.3445739746094"],
["Balin Sankar","10","History","87.1235580444336"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Geography","88.2675628662109"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Civics","89.6238479614258"],
["Balin Sankar","10","Economics","86.5236434936523"]]

var result = _.sortBy(data, item => parseFloat(item[3]))

var output = document.getElementById('result')

_.each(result, item => output.textContent += (item[2] + ' ' + item[3] + '\n'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.2/lodash.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```